# How to make the accordion effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make the `accordion` effect on this code, like [this sample](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 boxcontainer">
        <span class="boxheader">
            1
        </span>
        <div class="box">
            ABC
        </div>
        <div class="boxfooter">
            DEF
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 boxcontainer">
        <span class="boxheader">
            2
        </span>
        <div class="box">
            ABC
        </div>
        <div class="boxfooter">
            DEF
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the `boxheader`, the `box` and `boxfooter` parts appear. How do I to deal this, please?

Comment: is this all your code? Cause this requires Jquery. I dont see you add it. Next to that, you need to add in the script area the function of the accordion and a div that is called accordion. Under your example is actually the sourcecode. So check that out.

Comment: @Dorvalla, I've updated my posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [slideToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method of jquery. Try the below code.

```
$("body").on("click",".boxheader",function(){
   $(".box").hide();
   $(".boxfooter").hide();
   $(this).parent().find(".box").slideToggle();
   $(this).parent().find(".boxfooter").slideToggle();
});
```

css:

```
.box,.boxfooter{
    display:none;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r36x2/2/)

Answer (score 2):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S49Xm/)

**The code was always given in the link you've specified.**

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
```